# Not able to use Nokia C2-00 as modem

Tags: usb-modem, nokia-pc-suite

I have Nokia PC suite. When trying to connect to the internet it shows "Installing data connecting drivers" and gets stuck here. Please tell me what to do. I have a Nokia C2-00 and Windows XP.